# Get All value from JSON Key ( jQuery )

Tags: jquery, json

How to get all value from **fields** key with the following JSON dumps using jQuery :

```
{
  "fields": [
    {
      "label": "Name",
      "field_type": "text",
      "required": true,
      "field_options": {
        "size": "medium"
      },
      "cid": "c1"
    }, {
      "label": "Email",
      "field_type": "text",
      "required": true,
      "field_options": {
        "size": "medium"
      },
      "cid": "c2"
    }
  ]
}
```

What I want is only get :

```
{
  "label": "Name",
  "field_type": "text",
  "required": true,
  "field_options": {
    "size": "medium"
  },
  "cid": "c1"
}, {
  "label": "Email",
  "field_type": "text",
  "required": true,
  "field_options": {
    "size": "medium"
  },
  "cid": "c2"
}
```

Comment: take some tutorials on using javascript objects. This is really trivial

Comment: Do you mean you want to get `[{/*...*/}, {/*...*/}]` instead of `{/*...*/}, {/*...*/}`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var originalJson = '{"fields":[{"label":"Name","field_type":"text","required":true,"field_options":{"size":"medium"},"cid":"c1"},{"label":"Email","field_type":"text","required":true,"field_options":{"size":"medium"},"cid":"c2"}]}'

var fieldsJson = JSON.parse(originalJson).fields;
```

if you want that as a json string add

```
var fieldsJsonString = JSON.stringify(fieldsJson)
```

Comment: except fields is an array so `JSON.parse(originalJson).fields[0];`

Comment: that returns only the first object inside the fields json, I'm assuming (form the question itself) he wants all of them

Answer (score 0):

Store the main json into a variable. You can access its key using :

variable.fields

Answer (score 0):

```
var o = {"fields":[{"label":"Name","field_type":"text","required":true,"field_options":{"size":"medium"},"cid":"c1"},{"label":"Email","field_type":"text","required":true,"field_options":{"size":"medium"},"cid":"c2"}]};
var labels = o.fields
```

You can then access the labels via a `for`.

```
for(var i = 0; i < labels.length; i++){
    console.log(labels[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When I use

```
var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(payload);
     console.log(obj.fields);
```

I get :

[Object { label="Email", field_type="text", required=true, more...}, Object { label="Name", field_type="text", required=true, more...}, Object { label="Subject", field_type="text", required=true, more...}, Object { label="Message", field_type="paragraph", required=true, more...}]

How to get :

```
{"label":"Name","field_type":"text","required":true,"field_options":{"size":"medium"},"cid":"c1"},{"label":"Email","field_type":"text","required":true,"field_options":{"size":"medium"},"cid":"c2"}
```

Comment: check my answer's update, it should cover this if you use the stringify part